# Throw std::runtime_error within Openmp region crashes the program

Tags: c++, exception, openmp

I am trying to speed up a specific part of a large program, the exception handling is done at high level, originally the code looks like

```
for(....)
{
...
   if(...)
   {
    throw std:: runtime_error("Terminated by user")
   }
}
```

Now I have changed it to something like

```
#pragma omp parallel for ...
for(....)
{
...
   if(...)
   {
    throw std:: runtime_error("Terminated by user")
   }
}
```

And now if termination is triggered, the program crashes, I am expecting this exception handling here can be done in an elegant way without changing the higher level stuff?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant exceptionhandling in OpenMP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828539/elegant-exceptionhandling-in-openmp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OpenMP specification](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf) mandates that exceptions thrown by some thread must be handled by the same thread and within the same `parallel` region (Section 2.5, p. 49):

> A `throw` executed inside a `parallel` region must cause execution to resume within the same `parallel` region, and the same thread that threw the exception must catch it.

Compilers like GCC enforce this requirement by wrapping the code of the parallel region with a catch-all construct similar to this:

```
try
{
   ...
}
catch
{
   terminate();
}
```

Thus, any exception that reaches the end of the `parallel` region uncaught will cause the program to abort.

The rule is actually stricter as it also applies to OpenMP constructs such as `for`, `critical`, `single`, etc. An exception thrown within such a construct must be caught within the same construct and by the thread that threw it.  In your case, it is the `for` construct that results in the termination as its implicit catch-all handler is reached before the implicit catch-all handler of the `parallel` region.

Comment: So I have to catch this exception within pragma for and propagate it to higher level?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with an explicit try/catch block or think of a more elegant approach like the one outlined in the question linked to by Adri C.S.