# Is it safe to use a C++ mutex in OpenMP code

Tags: c++, c++11, openmp

Is it safe to use a C++11 `std::mutex` inside OpenMP 4.5 code? The idea is that I am using a logging library which protects each `std::cout` using a C++ mutex so that the outputs to `cout` are not scrambled when running with multiple threads. Inside my OpenMP code I may want to use this logging library to print some messages. Is it safe to do so?

Comment: I would say its okay. Obviously if your logging a lot in each thread the mutex will halt contending threads.

Comment: You can usually achieve the same effect by not doing `std::cout << ... << ... << ...` but rather packing the whole thing into a string and only outputting to `std::cout` once, i.e. `std::cout << my_message;`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe.

Only the very latest OpenMP version (5.0) even "specifies" the interaction with C++11 features. It does so by saying that using the "C++11 library [...] may result in unspecified behavior".

Practically, it may very well work, but working in "unspecified behavior land" is never desirable. You might find an implementation that goes beyond the standard and allows such combinations.

When it comes to mutexes, the recommendation it to stay within one paradigm and use the mutexes provided by OpenMP.